# ar_kinect node not found

Tags: ros, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a possibility how I can check that a node exists in a package?

Because in the ar_kinect package should be the ar_kinect node, but when I start the launch file, I get the error message that there is no node like this in this package.

Am I right that this node should be in ar_kinect package after I download this package?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42277/ar_kinect-node-not-found/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on 2012-08-26**:
I execute the "rosmake" command, but it does not help, but I found the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you remember to compile the package after you downloaded it? If not you should open a terminal, navigate to the package and execute the "rosmake" command.

---

Originally posted by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) with karma: 289 on 2012-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0